# regex for a string that does NOT contain a certain phrase not working in `list.files`

Tags: r, regex

I want to remove a certain element from a list of files/folders that I‘ve read in with `list.files`.

I.e. the result of my list.files contains several files and one folder that does end with '_files', e.g. `c('test.html', 'test_files')`.

I want to remove the folder from that list.

It works when I have the list of files/folders and then do sth. like `stringr::str_subset(c('test.html', 'test_files'), '^(?!.*_files).*$')`.

However, if I specify the above regex in the list.files command as the `pattern` argument, I‘m getting an error that the pattern argument is invalid.

What am I missing and how can I directly return a list of files that does not contain elements ending with '_files'?

Comment: In `list.files`, the regex flavor isTRE, it does not support lookaheads.

Comment: If you need to match a string not containing `_files`, you can use `^([^_]|_(_|f(_|i(_|l(_|e_))))*([^_f]|f([^_i]|i([^_l]|l([^_e]|e[^_s])))))*(_(_|f(_|i(_|l(_|e_))))*(f(i?|ile?))?)?$`

Comment: Phew. Ok, then I will rather return all elements and do the subsetting with str_subset with the full list of files. Thanks for the hint to the regex usage of list.files.